# How to add minimum 3 serial ports to a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: communication, raspberry-pi

How to add  at minimum 3 serial ports to a Raspberry Pi?

I thought about:

1) On hardware

2) On USB

For the the second one i thought about some circuit that exposes 3 serial ports and has an USB port that connects to the Pi. I.e.

```
                 |===COM1
USB=======circuit|===COM2
                 |===COM3
```

Comment: A USB hub with 3 FTDI devices attached to it would work.

Comment: @pjc50

but is there a chip that can do like a hub to do a micro HUB

Comment: Acutally I think this is the device you want: http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT4232H.htm

Comment: @pjc50 Yes it is! now i look for prototyping version THANKS +1

Comment: You see, this is exactly the reason I sneer at the Open Hardware community's efforts with Raspberry Pi. I think that the Arduino itself is an overkill for most projects, as far as computational power goes (how much MIPS do you need to light an LED?). And here is a prime example. The Raspberry Pi is packed with tons of stuff most people won't be able to use, and you still want to complement its functionality with external circuitry. You paid plenty for the Pi, I'm sure what you want to accomplish can be done by software alone. If you're unable to write that code, downgrade to cheaper kits.

Comment: Does this belong on the Raspberry Pi forum instead?  There are several questions related to this topic over there.  http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=serial

Comment: Wouldn't one need to know what the user was trying to do with the COM ports before one would know whether the Pi was overkill?

Comment: @JonnyBGood yes I agree! I no need a 3d card or hdmi quality but if I use an Arduino logging data from 3 serial port at the same time(my original question) is a bit complex but can be done, and then trasmit it over the lan is also complex because you need to do a lot of code to reinvent the weel. But yes when you have done you have a tailored hardware. I think rasperry is cheap enogh, think about peoplr that suggested to use a PC. 
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/50618/com-buffering-micro-pc-to-store-data-and-transmit-over-lan

Comment: @tcrosley I don't know about http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=serial Anyway Yes it could but this came from this question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/50618/com-buffering-micro-pc-to-store-data-and-transmit-over-lan   and the solution based on usb is general purpose  if i had accepted a HW solution it is in wrong place.

Comment: @ScottSeidman my original question was http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/50618/com-buffering-micro-pc-to-store-data-and-transmit-over-lan

Comment: I add a intersting solution but not the most simple

http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3475/how-to-get-more-than-one-uart-interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a ready built module from FTDI:

http://apple.clickandbuild.com/cnb/shop/ftdichip?productID=116&op=catalogue-product_info-null&prodCategoryID=89

Otherwise build around the FT4232H.
(Moved this to an answer so you can mark it accepted)